# Web Response 'an error occured while sending this request' while trying to login into Rockstar social club page

Tags: c#, authentication

I want to login to Rockstar Social Club page https://pl.socialclub.rockstargames.com
I have this script

```
public static void Login()
    {
        string firstUrl = "https://pl.socialclub.rockstargames.com/profile/signin"; 
        string formParams = string.Format("login-field={0}&password-field={1}", "mynickname", "mypassword");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(firstUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
        string pageSource;
        string getUrl = "https://pl.socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/pc/career/overview/gtaonline";
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse(); //Here returns me this error: System.Net.WebException: 'An error occurred while sending the request"

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
```

Error occures in `WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();`

> System.Net.WebException: 'An error occurred while sending the request'

I don't know how to repair this, and succesfully login to this website.

Comment: Hacking a web site is not as simple as it looks at first.

Comment: I am not hacking website, just logging to my account using program

Comment: Lets say you are not trying to became a hacker(wink wink), you need to give more info on http requests. Try using fiddler to sniff the traffic and look what you are missing. The login call should not work because of the CSRF token in the login (__RequestVerificationToken) also they use reCAPTCHA. All of this is intended to stop bots from logging in.

Comment: It is only hacking if he is not using his own credentials.
This, what he is doing, is Automation - albeit with a headless browser approach.
Many valid and reasonable reasons for this question, besides assuming malice. I myself -in my answer, describe one such reason for doing this - in my case, I was constructing an API to use with another gaming site. The site I was integrating with had no public API, so I used page scraping to acquire the data I needed.

Comment: @Baaleos I was joking to some extent, but this can be forbidden by terms and conditions (instagram doesn't allow scrolling and copyright of the content can be owned by someone other then the website in question). In general I don't think he will get into legal trouble if he is just playing around but I am not a giving legal advice. Hacking is defined as using a software in a way other then intended by the creator. [Here is a fun article on this stuff](https://benbernardblog.com/web-scraping-and-crawling-are-perfectly-legal-right/)

Comment: I think the discussion is straying from the topic at hand. He wants to gain authorized access to a website.Its authorized because he will have his own valid credentials. Even if Rockstar have a terms of use clause that says that you are not allowed to programmatically login, it does not detract from the technical or informative value of knowing how to perform that action - solving the problem he faces today, may be useful later on in his career - I myself work in Automation in a Software company, so solving this problem could have reuse value for viewers and the original poster in the future.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a platform to advocate for morals. There are legitimate applications for his question and I think you need to be made aware that a breech of 'terms of service' does not necessarily constitute a breach of law to the extent of criminal activity. At most, the website in this case would withhold services to the person found to be logging in programmatically. Code is neither good or bad (morally), and if you insist on Stack Overflow only hosting solutions that you agree with, then that's a form of censorship and it prevents the sharing of ideas and new solutions to problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished what you are attempting to do, but on a different website.
Basically - a few years ago, I wanted to create a website that would track my Guild/Company details on Final Fantasy XIV.

They didn't have an API, so I made one.

In order to get the information I required, I needed to use a mix of HtmlAgilityPack along with the C# WebBrowser control.

In order to pass the verification token stage above, you need to run the page source in a Web Browser control.
This will allow dynamic fields and data to be generated.
You then need to take that data, and submit it with your post data.

This is to fool it into thinking the request is coming from the page.

Be warned, when doing your posts - you may need to allow for redirects and you may need to mirror the referrer and host fields to match the website you are emulating.

The specific process I followed was:

Navigate to login page in WebBrowser control
Get page source
Load into HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument class
Use XPath to scrape the login form.
Take _verification tokens, csrf tokens etc make note of them.
Post a web-request with the necessary data to the form target destination url.

Read the response
Be aware - sometimes the response will actually be html code that tells it to do a Javascript redirect - in my case with Final Fantasy XIV - it was loading up another form and performing an autopost on page load.

You will also want to use

LoggedInCookies = new CookieContainer();

In your first HttpWebRequest
followed by:
request.CookieContainer = LoggedInCookies;

for each subsequent request.

The cookie container will trap and persist the authentication related cookies, while the WebBrowser control and HtmlAgilityPack will allow you to scrape the fields from the web forms that you need to break through.

Adding some code from wayback when I solved this for Final Fantasy XIV's lodestone website.
This code is very old and may not work anymore, but the process it follows could be adapted for sites that do not use Javascript as part of the login process.
Pay attention to the areas where it allows the request to be redirected, this is because the Server endpoint you are calling may do Action redirects etc
If your request does not allow those redirects, then it will not be emulating the login process.

```
class LoggedInClient
    {

        public static CookieContainer LoginCookie(string user, string pass)
        {
            string sStored = "";
            string url = "http://eu.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/account/login/";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(cookies.Count.ToString());
            string sPage = "";
            using (var vPage = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sPage = vPage.ReadToEnd();
            }

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sPage);
            sStored = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='_STORED_']").Attributes["value"].Value;
            string param = "sqexid="+user+"8&password="+pass+"&_STORED_=" + sStored;
            string postURL = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@name='mainForm']").Attributes["action"].Value;
            //Console.WriteLine(sStored);
            postURL = "https://secure.square-enix.com/oauth/oa/" + postURL;

            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] paramAsBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(param);

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postURL);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(paramAsBytes, 0, paramAsBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
            }

            string sGETPage = "";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var vPage = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    sPage = vPage.ReadToEnd();
                    sGETPage = response.Headers["Location"];
                }

            }

           // Console.WriteLine(sPage);
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sGETPage);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(cookies.Count.ToString());
            sPage = "";
            using (var vPage = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sPage = vPage.ReadToEnd();
            }


           // Console.WriteLine(sPage);

            doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sPage);
            string _c = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='_c']").Attributes["value"].Value;
            string cis_sessid = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='cis_sessid']").Attributes["value"].Value;
            string action = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@name='mainForm']").Attributes["action"].Value;
            string sParams = "_c=" + _c + "&cis_sessid=" + cis_sessid;
            byte[] bData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sParams);



           // Console.WriteLine(sStored);
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            try
            {

                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
            }

            string nextPage = "";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (var vPage = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    nextPage = vPage.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }

          //  Console.WriteLine(nextPage);

            doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(nextPage);
            string csrf_token = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='csrf_token']").Attributes["value"].Value;
            string cicuid = "51624738";

            string timestamp = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString() + "100";
            action = "http://eu.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/api/account/select_character/";
            sParams = "csrf_token=" + csrf_token + "&cicuid=" + cicuid + "&timestamp=" + timestamp;
            bData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sParams);
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36";
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.ToString());
            }
            nextPage = "";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (var vPage = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    nextPage = vPage.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }


            return cookies;
        }
    }
```